# Invoke a function when renaming node?

Tags: godot, gdscript

pretty straight forward Q, How do I invoke a function when the node is renamed?

I thought maybe `_set()` function would be invoked but it doesn't work for renaming

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `name` *from the editor* bypasses `_set()`. You can use `_set()` for intercepting when you set the `name` from code.

---

Another option is to connect the `"Renamed"` signal (all `Node`s have it).

You can connect as early as `_init` if you want it to happen before whatever code is instancing the `Node` has a chance to change its name.

However, this one only triggers if the `Node` is inside the scene tree.

---

And, finally, a way to detect changes of `name` *regardless of how the change happens* is to listen for the `NOTIFICATION_PATH_CHANGED` notification.

You get `NOTIFICATION_PATH_CHANGED` in `_notification` by default, no need to enable it or anything like that.

It even works when the `Node` is not in the scene tree, which I find surprising.

Even more surprising, it does not trigger when adding the `Node` to the scene tree, or removing it (those would be `NOTIFICATION_ENTER_TREE` and `NOTIFICATION_EXIT_TREE` respectively), despite those actions changing the path the node. So I believe `NOTIFICATION_PATH_CHANGED` is a misnomer, it should be "NOTIFICATION_NAME_CHANGED".